# Android Manufacturers with its own fingerprint / face . id SDK

Tags: android, fingerprint, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api, face-id

I am developing an app that uses fingerprint or face id to authenticate user.

Since 6.0 Marshmellow, Android includes the API to ease out the implementation of fingerprint sensors.

Is there a list of all the devices that are not compatible with this API? either because they were developed pre 6.0 or because their OEMs still doesn't want to use the Google API.

Or how do one know how to support the maximum amount of devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wonders, the only devices that fall into this are:

```
Samsung Galaxy S5
Samsung Galaxy S5 mini
Samsung Galaxy S5 plus
Samsung Galaxy Note 4
Samsung Galaxy Note Edge
```

All are samsung and can be validated with the *deprecated* Pass SDK.

After Android M was announced all manufactured devices with fingerprint sensor are compatible with Google fingerprint API.

Also, all devices with face unlock are compatible with Google Pie biometrics API and no OEM developed its own SDK.

Answer (score -1):

Two parts to this answer.

**First Part**

Devices that integrated a fingerprint sensor before the [`FingerprintManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager) API was introduced in API23 (M), that later updated to API23 may or may not be eligible to integrate with parts of the FingerprintManager API, which has specific security requirements. Namely, biometric matching [**must**](https://source.android.com/security/authentication/fingerprint-hal) be performed in a secure environment, such as the TEE.

On devices that do not meet the requirements, `KeyStore` operations (e.g. [`FingerprintManager#authenticate(CryptoObject)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html#authenticate(android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.CryptoObject,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20int,%20android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) will fail in certain ways, such as [`UserNotAuthenticatedException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/UserNotAuthenticatedException) when attempting to use a key, even after authentication was "successful".

**Second Part**

To support the maximum number of devices, it's recommended to use the [androidx.biometric](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric) library. On devices before the framework's [BiometricManager/BiometricPrompt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/package-summary) APIs were introduced, it will internally invoke FingerprintManager and show a support version of a system dialog. On newer APIs where BiometricManager/BiometricPrompt exist, it invokes the system/OEM's implementation of the API. OEMs are allowed to integrate biometrics that meet the various [CDD requirements](https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd#7_3_10_biometric_sensors).

Additionally, it follows the androidx release schedule, which allows for much faster bug-fixes compared to the platform (e.g. weekly instead of yearly)

Comment: This doesn't even address the question